# Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'InputObject'

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am trying to install Sitecore XC09 with SQL Server 2016 running on a separate  server. The script terminates with the attached error.

I am running the Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1 provided in the sitecore commerce bundle.

> Restarting SQL Server Something went wrong restarting SQL server again
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate argument on parameter
>   'InputObject'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that
>   is not null or empty, and then try the command again. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641
>   char:25
>   + & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:00:14 Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate
>   argument on parameter 'InputObject'. The argument is null or empty.
>   Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
>   command again. At
>   C:\sitecorecommerce\SIF\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:80 char:2
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:01:05 Invoke-ManageCommerceServiceTask : Cannot validate
>   argument on parameter 'InputObject'. The argument is null or empty.
>   Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
>   command again. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641
>   char:25
>   + & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageCommerceServiceTask

Error Details : It says "Something went wrong restarting SQL Server again" and gives the error stack as shown in image above.

Comment: I found the solution to above problem, this problem occurs when you re-run the commerce installation script. Before re-running you need to delete all Website, Application Pools and Folders in wwwroot folder of Sitecore Commerce 9 update 2.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes SQL Server Windows service cannot restart after stopping, ensure SQL Server Window service is running.

Also please make sure that TCP/IP protocol is enabled for the SQL server.

https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2015/tcpip-is-disabled-by-default-in-microsoft-sql-server-2014

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the same error, the above solution did not work for me.